# Is it possible to conditionally include CSS?

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have an ascx that has some CSS in it.  It is possible that this ascx could be added multiple times to a page.  The CSS that it uses would only need to be included once.

1. Is it possible to conditionally include CSS?  If so how?
2. Is this considered bad practice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have an ascx that has some CSS in it... Is this considered bad practice?

Yes. Your CSS rules should ideally be defined in a separate, static css file that gets loaded only once in the header by your master page. CSS in the body is not standards compliant.

If you set up good caching rules on your static CSS files, this will significantly reduce the amount of data you pull across the wire because the CSS rules won't need to be loaded again for each page load. If you want to only include this file in the header if certain dependent ASCX files get rendered, look at [Neil Fenwick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7150833/is-it-possible-to-conditionally-include-css/7150861#7150861).

#### Update

For whatever reason, Neil Fenwick seems to have deleted his answer. Hopefully he won't mind my reproducing it here:

> Definitely YES, it is possible.
>
> I would recommend looking at a library like [ClientDependency](http://clientdependency.codeplex.com/) to manage your CSS and JS includes & dependencies.
>
> Good examples for how to include given on ClientDependency codeplex page.
> Its good practice to organise your CSS and JS dependencies so that you can assert their requirement multiple times, but only emit the dependency in the output once.

Comment: So are you saying I should include styles on every single page for an ascx control that may only exist on 5% of pages on the site?

Comment: @Abe Miessler: No, I'm saying CSS rules should not exist in the body of the HTML. Read my last sentence. There are options for only including references for those 5% of pages that actually call your ASCX. But wouldn't it be nice if those 5% of pages could (a) be HTML compliant and (b) load a cached file instead of having all the same repetitive CSS rules?

Comment: @Neil Fenwick, Is there an a reason you deleted your answer?  It's looked pretty promising and I'm sure other users would like to see it...

Comment: @Abe Miessler: I agree. I included his answer's text in mine until he decides to resurrect it.

Answer (score 1):

The `ClientScriptManager` can handle this simply by checking whether or not some particular "script" has been added. Intended for javascript, but works for anything.

```
if(!Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("mykey")) {
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "mykey", "<link type=\"text/css\" href=\"stylesheet.css\"/>", false);
}
```

Comment: Would this add it to the Head or within the body?

Comment: RegisterClientStartupScript renders the text in the body tag, not the head tag.  :(  Many times I've wished that weren't the case!  (see also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerstartupscript%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You might be very interested in looking into [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/download/) which allows you to do plenty of interesting test and load different resources (for example CSS) depending on test result. For example you might want to load rounded-images.css if the browser does not support border-radius etc.

Comment: Does Modernizr really support the feature that the OP was asking for?  Namely to prevent the inclusion of the same CSS file multiple times due to the use of partials/controls?

Comment: You are right that directly it does not provide this exact functionality. You can however control which CSS are loaded via Modernizr rather than from partials. You might be right that it might not be desired in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Building on [Neil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7150833/is-it-possible-to-conditionally-include-css/7150861#7150861).  We make use of [Telerik's ASP MVC extensions](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/web-assets.html) to manage our JavaScript and CSS in ASP.NET MVC. It allows for "smart" inclusion of JS and CSS (even from a partial-view) preventing file duplication.  It comes with other bells-and-whistles as well (like file merging and compression).

*This is probably not applicable to your exact situation based on your post (raw ASP.NET), but thought I would mention it for the sake of ASP.NET MVC users looking for the same thing.*

Answer (score -2):

Put that in the head of the html.

```
<pre>
<!--[if gte IE 8]>         
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-up.css" />  <![endif]-->
</pre>
```

For more info go to: http://css-tricks.com/132-how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/
GTE means greater than.

Horrible practice. Unless that is all you do at your work since that is going to create a big workload since each css file might need to be changed in the future.

Comment: Not relevant, right?  The OP is looking to prevent the same CSS file from being loaded if it's already loaded on the page.